# Arduino button-controlled LED with AVR Assembly

Tags: arduino-uno, led, button, assembly

I am trying to make a simple button-controlled LED, but I cannot seem to get any input from the button that would change the state of the LED. In other words, the program keeps branching to lighton, keeping the LED always on, regardless of the button state. I am using an Elegoo Uno R3.

Schematic:
[image]

Code:

```
.text
.global setup
.global loop

setup:
  ser r16
  sts DDRB, r16
  ldi r16, 0b00000000
  sts DDRD, r16
  ldi r16, 0b00100000
  sts PORTB, r16
  clr r16
  sts PORTD, r16

loop:
  lds r20, PORTD
  cpi r20, 0x00 ; PORTD always equal to 0x00 ?
  breq lighton
  clr r16
  sts PORTB, r16
  rjmp loop
lighton:
  ldi r16, 0b00100000
  sts PORTB, r16
  rjmp loop
```

Edit: I also implemented the method in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361410/creating-a-toggle-switch-in-avr-assembly to create a short delay with `r18` instead of `del`, but it didn't help; see revised loop method below:

```
loop:
  cpi r18, 0
  brne dec_jmp
  lds r20, PORTD
  cpi r20, 0x00 ; PORTD always equal to 0x00 ?
  breq lighton
  clr r16
  sts PORTB, r16
  ldi r18, 250
  rjmp loop
lighton:
  ldi r16, 0b00100000
  sts PORTB, r16
  ldi r18, 250
  rjmp loop

dec_jmp:
  dec r18
  rjmp loop
```

With delay:

```
lighton:
  ldi r16, 0b00100000
  sts PORTB, r16
  call delay150
  ldi r16, 0b00000000
  sts PORTB, r16
  call delay150
  rjmp loop
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361410/creating-a-toggle-switch-in-avr-assembly

Comment: See edit in post

Comment: You have two potential problems in he setup: 1. You test not only PortB-bit2 (=Arduino pin 2), but all the pins of PortB. As these are floating your test (cpi r20 0x00) will never come true and the branch to lighton will never happen. 2. Your button will suffer from bouncing (google on this). Because of the 1st problem the LED should stay OFF. But it stays ON, so there is something else wrong. Break he program in small(er) parts and test each part on it's own. Did you try to switch the LED on and of by software alone (with a delay in between and not looking at the state of the switch)?

Comment: PORTB-bit2 corresponds to Pin13, which is the output pin that I am using. From what I understand, the branch to `lighton` is always happening and that's the problem. For example, I removed the line that sets PORTB in the `setup` method, and the LED remains on. So, Pin13 is constantly being set at `lighton`. Also, I did try the LED by itself with a delay and it works normally.

Comment: are you sure that the button is wired correctly? is the voltage on pin3 changing when you press the button?

Comment: Why did you connect a second LED to pin 13? You can as well used the LED that's already there (on the Arduino). Change the test to only test bit2 and not all the bytes from PortD (mask them out bij AND with 0x04). Even if you do that you still have the bouncing problem. Put a delay of a couple of seconds in so that you can see what happens in every loop. What happens when you replace the button with a piece of wire (like the button always closed), or when you take the button out (like button always open)?

Comment: See answer below

Comment: Just for the record: If you work with an Arduino Uno then Pin13 is on-board connected to a yellow LED via a non-inverting opamp and a resistor. Because of the opamp the load on the pin is negligible. - The setup of the other pins of PORTD is not so important. What is important is that you only test the status of pin2: `lds r20 PORTD` / `andi r20 0b00000100` / `breq lighton` (the `andi` instruction sets the other bits to zero, so that the `breq` is based on the value of Pin2 only).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with the below code for the loop:

```
loop:
  sbic PIND, 2
  call nopressb
  ; button pressed
  ldi r16, 0b00100000
  out PORTB, r16
  rjmp loop
nopressb:
  ldi r16, 0b00000000
  out PORTB, r16
  rjmp loop
```

Comment: Why do you use a `call` to jump to `nopressb`? `call` is ment to call a subroutine and stores the return address on the stack. Because you never return from a subroutine the stack will overflow.